# Create CSV file in each subdirectory of target directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have folder with files as below:

```
D:\TESzz\Background\BG_Flash-Zootopia-HD-Desktop-Wallpapers.jpg
D:\TESzz\Background\BG_NimmHBD.jpg
D:\TESzz\Background\BG_Note5.jpg
D:\TESzz\Icons\150x150.jpg
D:\TESzz\Icons\Bathroom-gender-sign.png
D:\TESzz\Icons\brocoli.png
D:\TESzz\Icons\Carrot_Clipart_PNG_Image.png
D:\TESzz\Icons\File.txt
D:\TESzz\Icons\garlic.png
D:\TESzz\Icons\ICONS.txt
D:\TESzz\Icons\NoppNimm-1.jpg
D:\TESzz\Icons\NoppNimmIcon.jpg
D:\TESzz\Icons\NoppNimmIcon.png
D:\TESzz\Icons\NoppProfie.jpg
D:\TESzz\Icons\NoppProfileSerious.jpg
D:\TESzz\Icons\pork.png
D:\TESzz\Icons\Profile.jpg
D:\TESzz\Icons\Questionmark.png
D:\TESzz\Icons\sugar.png
D:\TESzz\Icons\Tree.png
D:\TESzz\Icons\wheel.png
```

I want to export list of file to each sub-folder under "D:\TeSzz" as below

```
D:\TESzz\Icons\Icons.csv
D:\TESzz\Background\Background.csv
```

I have my code as below. but it will create "FileList.csv" instead of "Icons.csv" or "Background.csv". :(

```
Get-ChildItem -path "D:\TESzz\" -directory | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem -file "$($_.fullname)" | Export-Csv "$(Join-path $_.fullname 'FileList.csv')"}
```

Could someone help me on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would introduce a variable for the current directory. You don't get your expected result because you are naming the output always as `FileList.csv`.

```
Get-ChildItem -path "D:\TESzz\" -directory | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $directory = $_
    Get-ChildItem -file $directory.FullName | 
        Export-Csv (Join-path $directory.FullName "$($directory.BaseName).csv") -Force
}
```

In the above, notice that where you had `FileList`, that's now `$($directory.BaseName)`, and therefore different for each directory.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, however i copy your code and paste to my Powershell. It's does generate file named ".csv" in both subdirectories without the BaseName.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the parent directory name in a variable, then use it to form the output file name:

```
$parentDir = "D:\TESzz";
Get-ChildItem -path $parentDir -directory | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem -name $parentDir\$_ | Export-Csv -path $(Join-path $parentDir\$_ ($_.Name+'.csv'))}
```

Here, we use `$parentDir` to create the export path.

Comment: I've edited your answer for readability, and it no longer merits the down-vote.  But please remember that although working code is useful, a good explanation helps both the asker and other readers how to apply the same knowledge to other problems, and can be the difference between a mediocre answer and a great one.  Thanks for taking the trouble to answer, and to improve it!