# Export sub-folder name as path and create a csv for each parent sub-folder in a different location

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to export the sub-folder names (as path) of each parent folder individually and create a csv for each one (1,2,3) in a different location.

Tree example looks like this:

```
C:\USERS\XXXXX\DESKTOP\TEST
├───1
│   ├───11
│   ├───111
│   └───1111
├───2
│   ├───22
│   ├───222
│   └───2222
└───3
    ├───33
    ├───333
    └───3333
```

Script I am using is:

```
$parentDir = "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Test";
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -Depth 2 -Attribute Directory -Path $parentDir | Select-Object -Property FullName | Export-Csv Test.csv
```

The problem is that it will show the result for the Test folder, I want to export the content of each sub-folder and create a csv with their name in a different location, the process has to be repeated for 42 folders and changing the $parentDir for each one is time consuming..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it might be better to do this using two Get-ChildItem commands:

```
$parentDir = "C:\USERS\XXXXX\DESKTOP\TEST"
$outputDir = "C:\USERS\XXXXX\DESKTOP"
Get-ChildItem -Path $parentDir -Force -Directory | ForEach-Object { 
    $outCsv = Join-Path -Path $outputDir -ChildPath "$($_.Name).csv"
    $_ | Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object FullName | Export-Csv -Path $outCsv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Using your example folders, this wil write 3 csv files on your desktop, named `1.csv`, `2.csv` and `3.csv` with content:

```
"FullName"
"D:\Test\1\11"
"D:\Test\1\111"
"D:\Test\1\1111"
```

```
"FullName"
"D:\Test\2\22"
"D:\Test\2\222"
"D:\Test\2\2222"
```

```
"FullName"
"D:\Test\3\33"
"D:\Test\3\333"
"D:\Test\3\3333"
```

For old PowerShell versions, the `-Directory` switch is not available and you should use

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $parentDir -Force | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { ... }
```

Comment: Tried something similar with two `Get-ChildItem` but the output was never the one expected.. also, never thought to use `$outCsv` in combination with `ChildPath`. That's great, thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

```
%{foreach( $a in (Get-ChildItem -Recurse) ){$a.FullName}} | Out-File neu.txt
Get-Content .\neu.txt | Convertto-Csv | Out-file mac.csv
```

I tried it this way.

Comment: The output was a single csv file. Would be preferable to export each sub-folder in a csv file with the same name (1,2,3), each with it's own sub-sub-folder paths as name such as: 
**1.csv** _C:\Temp\Test\11_;_C:\Temp\Test\111;_C:\Temp\Test\1111)
**2.csv** _C:\Temp\Test\22_;_C:\Temp\Test\222;_C:\Temp\Test\2222)
**3.csv** _C:\Temp\Test\33_;_C:\Temp\Test\333;_C:\Temp\Test\3333)
I have found some info on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160105) however, I am not sure how to integrate that with `Select-Object -Property FullName` and export the output to a different location